# Meshing in a voxel game

Tags: java, 3d, mesh, voxel

I'm currently working on a render system for my voxel-based mapping system (similiar to Minecraft). Right now, I'm just trying to render 1 chunk at a time. A Chunk consists of a 3d array of Blocks, each Block consists of 6 faces (North, East, South, West, Top, Bottom). So far so good.

When looking into the best way to render a chunk on screen, I came across a technique called greedy meshing. The maths for the optimal version is beyond me unfortunately, so I'm implementing a simplified version called naive greedy meshing. The idea is pretty simple: For each side, go through each layer of the chunk, and try to construct the largest possible mesh consisting of the same blocktypes (in this case, a 10*10 block of cubes becomes 1 mesh, instead of 100 cube meshes). I do this by obtaining a 2d slice of the chunk for each layer for each side, and then comparing this to a mask (simple 2d boolean array) which keeps track of already masked blocks. The end result works quite nicely, except for the fact that once the mask has been set, it will not take into account airblocks on lower z-levels. [image: This chunk is missing meshes for the air block in the middle]
As can be seen, there is an airblock in the middle of the bottom half of the chunk, with a dirt block behind it. From the north, this works perfectly as the mask is not set to true for the position of the airblock. When it gets to the next z-level (the one behind it) it creates a mesh for the missing block in the mask. However, from the east side, the entire mask is filled on the first layer (bottom half with rock, top half with air, 2 quads in total) So once it gets to the z-level with the airblock, it is ignored because the side is already masked.

How can I get around this problem, where a side might be meshed correctly already, but there are empty spaces further behind that layer that also require meshing? I can't simply clear the mask for each z-level, as that would lead to invisible layers being meshed.

Code for a Block:

```
public class Block {
    private BlockType type;
    private BlockFace[] faces;
    public BlockType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public BlockFace[] getFaces() {
        return faces;
    }

    public Block(BlockType type) {
        this.type = type;
        this.faces = new BlockFace[6];
        initFaces();
    }



    Block(Block block) {
        this(block.getType());
    }

    private void initFaces() {
        int idx=0;
        for(BlockSide side : BlockSide.values()) {
            this.faces[idx] = new BlockFace(type, side);
            idx++;
        }
    }
}
```

Code for a Chunk:

```
public class Chunk {
    public static int CHUNK_SIZE = 10;
    public static int BLOCK_SIZE = 1;
    private Block[][][] blocks;

    public Chunk() {
        this.blocks = new Block[CHUNK_SIZE][CHUNK_SIZE][CHUNK_SIZE];
    }

    public void fillChunk(Block block) {
        for(int x=0; x<CHUNK_SIZE; x++) {
            for(int y=0; y<CHUNK_SIZE; y++) {
                for(int z=0; z<CHUNK_SIZE; z++) {
                    blocks[x][y][z] = new Block(block);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setBlock(Block block, int x, int y, int z) {
        blocks[x][y][z] = new Block(block);
    }

    public Block getBlock(int x, int y, int z) {
        return this.blocks[x][y][z];
    }

    public Block getBlockRelativeToSide(BlockSide side, int x, int y, int z) {
        switch(side) {
            case NORTH:
                return getBlock(CHUNK_SIZE-1-x, y, z);
            case SOUTH:
                return getBlock(x, y, CHUNK_SIZE-1-z);
            case EAST:
                return getBlock(CHUNK_SIZE-1-z, y, CHUNK_SIZE-1-x);
            case WEST:
                return getBlock(z, y, x);
            case TOP:
                return getBlock(x, CHUNK_SIZE-1-z, CHUNK_SIZE-1-y);
            case BOTTOM:
                return getBlock(x, z, y);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void print(int y) {
        System.out.println("Printing for level:" + y);
        for(int z=0; z<CHUNK_SIZE; z++) {
            String row = "";
            for(int x=0; x<CHUNK_SIZE; x++) {
                switch(blocks[x][y][z].getType()) {
                    case AIR:
                        row += "[ ]";
                        break;
                    case DIRT:
                        row+= "[D]";
                        break;
                    case ROCK:
                        row+= "[R]";
                        break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(row);
        }        
    }
}
```

Note: The method `getBlockRelativeToSide()` allows you to specify a side, x, y, and z coordinates. This method makes sure that you're always dealing with x as left-to-right, y as bottom to top, and depth from near to far. So `getBlockRelativeToSide(SOUTH, 0, 0, 0)` would be the absolute position 0, 0, 9 in a chunk with size 10. `getBlockRelativeToSide(EAST, 0, 0, 0)` would be the bottom left, first layer position as seen from the east (absolute position 9, 0, 9).